# Can Rails avoid picking VERSION environment variable in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, centos7

I want to host a Ruby on Rails application in a server with `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`.

Every time I SSH into the server I get an environment variable `VERSION` with value `7` by default.

When I try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, `Version=7` is automatically being picked by Rails and I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError:
No migration with version number 7
```

If I manually deploy the Rails app, I can `unset VERSION` and run the `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.
But `unset VERSION` is not working somehow with Capistrano auto deployment.

So, I am looking for a work around to run migrate task with Capistrano.

Is there an option in Rails where we can specify migrate task not to look for `VERSION` environment variable in production.

Comment: I don't know centos, but is VERSION perhaps set somewhere in your .bashrc or something? So you could just remove that line (not sure how safe that would be)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the comment. No I don't find VERSION in `bashrc` or `bash_profile`.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30707

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Looks like this issue is discussed in that thread without a solution for positive VERSION number.

Comment: Yes. Which means there's no solution on rails side, yet.

Comment: If you cant change the rails behaviour you could find from where the VERSION env variable comes, use env with different users to check if that env variable exists for your specific user only or if it is global. There not exists a VERSION environment variable for CentOS 7 by default, so it must have been added manually or by configuration (init scripts, services...).

Comment: @vzamanillo VERSION seems to be available globally for all users. Is there a way to find from where it is coming from ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea from where the variable comes, probably from a script or service, check systemd services and init scripts :/, maybe in /etc/environment...

Comment: @vzamanillo I found from where `VERSION` is coming . I am using my company's private cloud and they are setting this in one of the init file within `/etc/profile.d/`.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Ok, I am going to put this on an answer to resume.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant change the rails behaviour you could find from where the `VERSION` env variable comes, use env with different users to check if that env variable exists for your specific user only or if it is global. There not exists a `VERSION` environment variable for CentOS 7 by default, so it must have been added manually or by configuration, check `systemd services` and `init scripts`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile.d`... etc